# How to rearrange methods in a Groovy file?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

Are there any tools or plugins to rearrange methods/fields/CTORs/etc in a .groovy file akin to Intellij's "Rearrange Code" or Rearranger plugin?

Neither the native Intellij 13 functionality nor the Rearranger plugin does code rearranging for groovy that I've found.

Comment: Rearranging methods and fields? As a standard? Why would anyone want something like that?

Comment: Is "why" an important question here?  Is there a way or is there not? If there is, what is it?

Comment: I too am looking for something to do this, 9 years later. As for the "why": CodeNarc has a check for StaticFieldsBeforeInstanceFields, and a quick way to rearrange Groovy class members would be very helpful.